# VB difference between windows file hour and VB file hour

Tags: vba, date, time, difference

How to obtain the date from a file without the influence of windows time settings ?

I'm trying to read date file with VB but I obtain a difference between the time writes on file properties (WDT) and the time returns by VB (VBT), due to daylight saving time

If I read a file saved during winter time in summer, I have a difference of VBT = WDT+1h. And in the same case, if I read a file saved during summer in winter, I obtain a difference of VBT = WDT-1h.

Comment: If you don't want local time then use properties like FileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc instead of FileInfo.LastWriteTime.  Not that it makes a difference but it does make it more obvious that 10 AM in the summer is not a multiple of 24 hours from 10 AM in the winter.

Comment: Retagged to VBA as it appears that is the language being used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the DateTime(s) to [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) and compare *those* times. This is the time without any adjustment for daylight savings, etc.

There is an extension of the `DateTime` type `ToUniversalTime` that returns the UTC value:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx

Example:

```
    Dim currentDateTime = DateTime.Now
    Debug.WriteLine(currentDateTime.ToString)
    Debug.WriteLine(currentDateTime.ToUniversalTime.ToString)
```

Outputs on my machine (UK Time Zone +1h from UTC for British Summer Time)

```
15/04/2016 12:21:04
15/04/2016 11:21:04
```

Note that there is also a `DateTime.UtcNow` if you want the current system time directly in UTC

Comment: I tried to implement this function but the type isn't recognized. An error message appears to say that Visual Basic doesn't handle Active X.

Comment: Are you sure you are using VB.NET and not VB6 or VBA or VB Script?

Comment: Actually, I'm using VBA.

Comment: Perhaps you might now be able to see how correctly tagging a question with the language you are using can help to reach a solution then?